# Trocar classe dinamica no mdDialog.show

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Preciso alterar a classe do botão OK, por padrão ela é dinâmica e vem setado 'md-primary'.

```
$mdDialog.show(
          $mdDialog.alert()
            .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#popupContainer')))
            .title('This is an alert title')
            .textContent('You can specify some description text in here.')
            .ariaLabel('Alert Dialog Demo')
            .ok('Got it!') // trocar a cor desse botão
          );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Você pode alterar via CSS mesmo:

```
#popupContainer button.md-primary {
  color: '#000' !important;
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

**2.** Ou também, você pode alterar a classe via Javascript:

```
var btnElement = document.querySelector('#popupContainer button.md-primary');
btnElement.classList.remove('md-primary');
btnElement.classList.add('minha-classe');
```

**3.** Você pode também criar seu próprio *template HTML* e passar como parâmetro para o *$mdDialog*:

```
$mdDialog.show({ 
  templateUrl: 'dialog1.html'
});
```

Veja mais exemplos na página da documentação do [Material Angular - Dialog](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog).

**OBS:** Não se esqueça de ver a documentação do Angular Material de acordo com a versão do arquivo que está utilizando no seu projeto. A versão da documentação fica no menu esquerdo do site, no primeiro item *Documentation Version*.